# Show spinner when ajax async is set to false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have created multi screen approach using ASP.MVC
For that purpose I am using single view with multiple div's concept(each div is each screen).

When user clicks next/previous button it will validate all client and server side validations then only it will go the next/previous screen(means div.show)

For the Server side calls I am using Ajax calls, the result will be true or false. Based on that the page will move to next/previous screen.

For that I set Async = false in ajax call. It means that it will wait for the server response other wise it can not wait for server response so that it leads to next/previous screen.

**Can anyone please suggest me the solution that how can we show the spinner for this approach..?** 
Here we should not follow the sessions concept so that we have chosen this single view with multiple div's approach.

Comment: You can show a loader image just before calling ajax request and hide that loader image in ajax success method.

Comment: I am doing that one only. but when we can use async=false it can freeze the ui. so that we could not show that spinner.

It is working fine when we can set async=true or remove that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

synchronous ajax calls will always freeze the browser. you should instead use asynchronous calls wrapped in jQuery's 
$.when().then();

```
$.when(function() {
    if (validateFunction()) {
        $.ajax(...);
    } else {
        // code the execute on not valid
    }
})
.then(function () {
    hideSpinner();
});
```

to keep the spinner active during your service call.

see documentation https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: Then it will go to next screen even it has error validations. We should validate all server validations then only we have to move to next screen

Comment: You can wrap your Ajax in a validation function that executes on valid info inside the $.when() I will update my pseudo code